# System.out.println printing twice in each iteration of while loop

Tags: java, game-loop

I am trying to figure out why I am getting two lines printed with each iteration of the while loop when I run this code:

```
public void run() {
    long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    long targetFPS = 1000;
    long delta;
    while(GameConstants.running) {
        delta = System.nanoTime() - currentTime;
        if(delta/1000000000 >= 1) {
            System.out.println(delta);
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust the code to just call `System.out.println()` once to debug, however it is still printing twice. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening since in this modified version, `System.out.println(delta)` is called, then printed is set to true so `System.out.println(delta)` should not be called again.

```
public void run() {
    long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    long targetFPS = 1000;
    long delta;
            boolean printed = false;
    while(GameConstants.running) {
        delta = System.nanoTime() - currentTime;
        if(delta/1000000000 >= 1 & !printed) {
            System.out.println(delta);
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                            printed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for context:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable, KeyListener {

    private Thread gameThread;

public synchronized void start() {
    if(GameConstants.running) return;
    GameConstants.running = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if(!GameConstants.running) return;
    GameConstants.running = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    long targetFPS = 1000;
    long delta;
            boolean printed = false;
    while(GameConstants.running) {
        delta = System.nanoTime() - currentTime;
        if(delta/1000000000 >= 1 && !printed) {
            System.out.println(delta);
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                            printed = true;
        }
    }
}

public void update() {
    if(GameConstants.gameState == 1 && !GameConstants.trialTypeDetermined ) {
        Random r = new Random();
        double prob = r.nextDouble();
        if(prob < GameConstants.goProb) {
            GameConstants.skipBad = true;
        }
        GameConstants.trialTypeDetermined = true;
        System.out.println(GameConstants.skipBad);
    }
      taskTimer(GameConstants.goTaskTimes.get(getGameState(GameConstants.gameState)));
    System.out.println(GameConstants.gameState);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void render() {

}

//
public String getGameState(int gameState){
    return GameConstants.gameStates[GameConstants.gameState];
}

private void skipBad() {
    Random r = new Random();
    double prob = r.nextDouble();
    if(prob < GameConstants.goProb) {
        GameConstants.skipBad = true;
    }
    GameConstants.trialTypeDetermined = true;
}

public void taskTimer(long taskTime) {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - GameConstants.startTime >= taskTime) {
        GameConstants.taskComplete = true;
        GameConstants.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        nextGameState();
        GameConstants.keyPressed = false;
    }
}

private void nextGameState() {
    if(GameConstants.gameState == 2 & GameConstants.skipBad) {
        GameConstants.gameState = GameConstants.gameState + 2;
    } else if(GameConstants.gameState != 5) {
        GameConstants.gameState++;
    } else {
        GameConstants.gameState = 1;
    }
    GameConstants.gameStateRegistered = false;
}

private void resetParameters() {

}

private void checkHit() {

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !GameConstants.keyPressed){
       GameConstants.keyPressed = true;
       if(!GameConstants.reached){
           GameConstants.reached = true;
           GameConstants.RT = System.currentTimeMillis();
       }
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GameConstants.WIDTH * GameConstants.SCALE, GameConstants.HEIGHT * GameConstants.SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(GameConstants.WIDTH * GameConstants.SCALE, GameConstants.HEIGHT * GameConstants.SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(GameConstants.WIDTH * GameConstants.SCALE, GameConstants.HEIGHT * GameConstants.SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.setSize(GameConstants.WIDTH * GameConstants.SCALE, GameConstants.HEIGHT * GameConstants.SCALE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();
    game.run();
}
}
```

Comment: How is `run()` called? Are there multiple threads? Why do you use `&` instead of `&&`? It shouldn't cause any problems but it is interesting.

Comment: Why do you say it prints twice per iteration of the while() loop?  Where are you counting / tracking iterations?

Comment: I'll respond once I figure out how to add code to comments, I can't add the code in an answer because I am a new user.

Comment: The *question*. Not an answer.

Comment: Why is this question still open ? It has been correctly answered in both answers below, you should close it.

Answer (score 4):

Your bootstrap code is flawed you are calling both `start` and `run` effectively running the code twice. Remove the call to `run`.

Comment: Ah, ok, this seemed to fix the problem. I thought I also had to call run as well since I did not call it elsewhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your `start` method creates a `Thread` and also starts it. That thread is already going to call the `run` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have started multiple thread on the same object, You should use synchronized block to run thread-safe code,

```
synchronized(this){

long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
long targetFPS = 1000;
long delta;
while(GameConstants.running) {
    delta = System.nanoTime() - currentTime;
    if(delta/1000000000 >= 1) {
        System.out.println(delta);
        currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
}
```

**After Updating Source Code**

Yeah! here, you are calling run() method and start both...

```
game.start();
game.run();
```

remove calling run method explicitly, you will get desired result :)